# Cannot convert type 'string' to 'float'

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am getting this error:

```
Cannot convert type 'string' to 'float'
```

on following lines of code:

```
float x=(float )(TextBox_item_price.Text);
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: Error message isn't clear? What is the value of `TextBox_item_price.Text` exactly?

Comment: Wow.. I just saw 8 answer (1 is deleted) and no one even care what is the value of `TextBox_item_price.Text` exactly and which `Culture` OP's using..

Comment: @SonerGönül Well, we can guess that author uses locale on his PC he is aware of and types number into the textbox in that format.

Comment: Why are you needing to use a float? Surely a double would be better?

Answer (score 6):

You need to do

```
float x = float.Parse(TextBox_item_price.Text);
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
float f; 
float.TryParse(TextBox_item_price.Text, out f);
```

Answer (score 0):

use this:

```
float x = float.Parse(TextBox_item_price.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

use Float.TryParse. This will return true if parsing is successful. Else false will be returned. No exception is thrown.

Like this

```
float x;
if (float.TryParse(TextBox_item_price.Text, out x))
{
            //success
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it wil work fine

```
float x=float.Parse(TextBox_item_price.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not use type casting between incompatible types, use [Single.TryParse](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.single.tryparse%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [Convert.ToSingle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tosingle.aspx)

> To convert between non-compatible types, such as integers and
>   System.DateTime objects, or hexadecimal strings and byte arrays, you
>   can use the System.BitConverter class, the System.Convert class, and
>   the Parse methods of the built-in numeric types, such as Int32.Parse.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
var a = string.Empty;
var b = float.Parse(a);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This:

```
(float)System.Convert.ToSingle(TextBox1.Text);
```

or this:

```
float.Parse(TextBox1.Text);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

You can use `float.Parse()` instead of using `float x=(float)();` it will works fine

Answer (score -1):

try this;

```
Convert.ToDouble(TextBox_item_price.Text)
```

instead of;

```
(float)(TextBox_item_price.Text);
```